# ASP.NET File Not Found for Custom Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I have deployed the same website application to two servers. On server A, the application works perfect. On server B, the below error message comes up when attempting to view a page that loads a specific custom control.

```
Error Message: The file '/Website/Controls/MyCustomControl.ascx' does not exist.
Stack Trace: at System.Web.UI.Util.CheckVirtualFileExists(VirtualPath virtualPath) at 
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) at 
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) at 
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) at
System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(VirtualPath virtualPath) at 
System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(String virtualPath)
```

The two servers are using the same version, and service pack of Microsoft Server

I have verified that the compiled DLLs for this control are within the bin directory of the website, and that the bins of the two website deployments are identical. The web configs of the two deployments are also identical, other than the connection strings used. The permissions on both websites have the APP POOL, IUSR, and the account used for hosting the website to have full control.

I have also verified that any DLLs referenced by the application that should reside in the GAC are installed into the GAC on both servers.

This particular control is loaded in the same way as other custom controls that have been verified to be working on both deployments.

Comment: what does the `virtualPath` parameter/instance look like, and is that user control part of your deployment/project?

Comment: did you verify that the file actually exists on the filesystem on server B, is there virtual directory on the website of server A (check, I presume, IIS)

Comment: are you using web deploy or deploying via filesystem? is the publish settings set to clear the directory?

Comment: the virtual path is "~/controls/MyCustomControl.ascx". The Custom Control resides in "website/controls/MyCustomControl.ascx" before the deploy, and gets compiled to a DLL within the bin during the build process. This DLL exists on server B, and there is no virtual directory in IIS for server A.

Comment: **"website/controls/MyCustomControl.ascx" before the deploy, and gets compiled to a DLL** if you are compiling the control, then you should not be attempting to compile and build it at runtime from a file, which is what the operation above is doing.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templatecontrol.loadcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx use `LoadControl(Type, Object[]) `where `Type` is type of the control